# Generating unique random numbers from non-unique random numbers

Tags: python, algorithm, random

The following function converts a list of non-unique random numbers into a list of unique random numbers using a helper list of sequential integers:

```
def get_d(rlist):
    # t[] is a list of ints 0..n-1 where n is big
    # enough not to cause issues when deleting items
    t  = list(range( len(rlist) + max(rlist) ))
    d  = []            # the output list we will populate
    for r in rlist:
        d.append(t[r]) # add r'th remaining item in t[] to d[]
        t.pop(r)       # delete that item from t[]
    return d
```

e.g.
get_d([3, 2, 3, 1, 5]) =  [3, 2, 5, 1, 9]

The reason for favouring this way of doing things is personal preference.  It strikes me as a very natural ordering and it seems like one of the most obvious ways of converting a list of integers into another while guaranteeing uniqueness.

I want to remove the dependance on the temporary list so that very large items can be accomodated without resorting to a very large list.
I'm open to other ways of ordereding the output but I'm most interested in an answer to getting the same output using a counting or other method.

This is my attempt, which has some edge case or perhaps more fundamental issues:

```
def get_e(r):
    e = []
    for i,t in enumerate(r):
        c = 0
        # track numbers <= the current one
        for j in range(i):
            if r[j] <= t:
                c+=1
        # track numbers <= the current one when virtual deletions are accounted for
        for j in range(i):
            if r[j] > t and r[j]-c <= t:
                c+=1
        e.append(t+c)
    return e
```

Here is a test:

```
for r in [ [3,2,3,1,5], [0,0,1,0,0]]:
    d = get_d(r)
    e = get_e(r)
    print('match:   ' if d==e else 'mismatch:', r, '  : ',  d, '  ', e)


Output: 
match:    [3, 2, 3, 1, 5]   :  [3, 2, 5, 1, 9]    [3, 2, 5, 1, 9]
mismatch: [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]   :  [0, 1, 3, 2, 4]    [0, 1, 3, 3, 4]
```

Comment: *"I would like to get the same output using a counting method or other method"* - Why?

Comment: Note that my question is two-fold: 1) Why do you want a different method, i.e., what's the problem with your current method, i.e., what/how are you trying to improve? 2) Why do you want that same output? There might be better methods achieving the same "purpose" but with different outputs.

Comment: In other words you want to replace duplicate numbers with unique random numbers, is that correct?

Comment: Trying to do this creates a **lot** of inherent bias issues. Why not just generate your numbers differently in the first place? Use `random.sample`, for example.

Comment: @user2357112, does it? Surely no more than [Fisher Yates](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)?

Comment: Hmm? What bias do you see in Fisher Yates?

Comment: @fundamental: It does. (The Fisher-Yates shuffle works entirely differently from what you're doing, and does not suffer from the same problems.) For example, suppose your inputs come from the sample space `[0, 0]`, `[0, 1]`, `[1, 0]`, `[1, 1]`. The corresponding outputs from your `get_d` are `[0, 1]`, `[0, 2]`, `[1, 0]`, and `[1, 2]`. `2` only ever appears as the second element, `0` and `1` appear more often than `2`, and the only possible descending output is `[1, 0]`.

Comment: @KellyBundy: none, that's the point I was making. The Fisher and Yates' original method referenced in the wiki link looks very similar to the method I was using.

Comment: @user2357112: I think I see what you mean.
However that seems to suggest that the original Fisher Yates method also has an issue - or at least the Wikipedia write-up and / or Pencil-and-paper method example.

The random numbers used were [3,4,5,3,4,1,2] and the result was C E G D H A F B

After adding 1 to the list of random numbers to pick up the last character and then subtracting 1 to allow for zero-based indexing, get_d() gives the same result:

 print( *['ABCDEFGH'[i] for i in \
    get_d( [x-1 for x in [3,4,5,3,4,1,2,1] ] )] )
 
C E G D H A F B

Comment: @fundamental: See how, in the Wikipedia article, it says "Pick a random number k between one and **the number of unstruck numbers remaining (inclusive)**."? That's very important, and entirely unlike how your code works.

Comment: Fisher-Yates generates random numbers in such a way that each possible sequence of random numbers corresponds 1-to-1 with a possible permutation of the input list. To do this, it has to pick random numbers from a different range for every element. Your code doesn't work like that.

Comment: @user2357112: my code made no mention whatsoever of how the random numbers were generated. 
Non-unique is all that was stated. That was meant to imply not necessarily distinct, which I think is clear since otherwise they would alll be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the following, which seems to do the trick, passing the test I showed above. It's much more involved than I expected and there's certainly room for optimisation.

```
def splitlist(t,i):
    c = t[0]+i
    a = [t[0],c-1]
    b = [c+1, t[1]]
    if c==0:
        return [[b],c]
    if c==t[1]:
        return [[a],c]
    return [[a,b],c]

def get_f(x):
    u = [[ 0, max(x) + len(x) ]]
    print(f'u: {u}')
    v = []
    for k in x:
        i = k
        for j,t in enumerate(u):
            L =  t[1]-t[0]+1 # "len(t)"
            if i < L:
                x,y = splitlist(t,i)
                break
            else:
                i-=L
        v.append(y)
        del u[j]
        if len(x) > 1:
            u.insert(j, x[1])
        u.insert(j, x[0])
        print(f'{k}->{y} : {u}')
    return v
```

The idea is to start off with something like this as input:

```
x = [ 5, 8, 0, 20, 15 ]
```

and make use of a helper list of lists, initialised as:

```
u = [ [0,25] ]
```

then keep finding and splitting the appropriate list within u as follows:

```
>>> get_f([5, 8, 0, 20, 15 ])
u: [[0, 25]]
5->5 : [[0, 4], [6, 25]]
8->9 : [[0, 4], [6, 8], [10, 25]]
0->0 : [[1, 4], [6, 8], [10, 25]]
20->23 : [[1, 4], [6, 8], [10, 22], [24, 25]]
15->18 : [[1, 4], [6, 8], [10, 17], [19, 22], [24, 25]]
[5, 9, 0, 23, 18]
```

which matches the original:

```
>>> get_d([5, 8, 0, 20, 15 ])
    [5, 9, 0, 23, 18]
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm open to other ways of ordereding the output

Ok, here's a similar method that doesn't have that issue with "very large items", simply increasing numbers as long as they'd duplicate:

```
def get_k(rlist):
    d = []
    for r in rlist:
        while r in d:
            r += 1
        d.append(r)
    return d
```

Turns `[3, 2, 3, 1, 5]` into `[3, 2, 4, 1, 5]`, for example.

If your list is long, you could use an additional set for more efficiency:

```
def get_k(rlist):
    d = []
    dset = set()
    for r in rlist:
        while r in dset:
            r += 1
        d.append(r)
        dset.add(r)
    return d
```

Answer (score 1):

Following OP's idea of using `max([])`

```
r = [3,2,3,1,5]
new = []
new.append(r[0])
m = max(r)
for i,n in enumerate(r):
    if i > 0:
        if n in new:
            new.append(m +1)
            m = max(new)
        else:
            new.append(r[i])

print(r)
print(new)
```

Only the duplicate element was changed

```
[3, 2, 3, 1, 5]
[3, 2, 6, 1, 5]
```

Testing with 10k random lists. Should generate no message.

```
import numpy as np

def gen_random_list():
    '''List of random integers with at least 1 duplicate'''

    data = np.random.randint(1,10,size=5)
    r = data.tolist()
    r1 = np.random.randint(0,4)
    r2 = np.random.randint(0,4)
    r[r1] = r[r2]
    return r

def build_new_random():
    #r = [3,2,3,1,5]
    r = gen_random_list()
    new = []
    new.append(r[0])
    m = max(r)
    for i,n in enumerate(r):
        if i > 0:
            if n in new:
                new.append(m +1)
                m = max(new)
            else:
                new.append(r[i])

    assert len(r) == len(new)


for i in range(1,10000):
    build_new_random()
```

This one is interesting since the duplicate element was also the `max()`

```
[8, 4, 8, 8, 7]
[8, 4, 9, 10, 7]
```

**Note**: don't name your testing file `random.py` as you will get this error

> AttributeError: partially initialized module 'numpy' has no attribute 'random' (most likely due to a circular import)